# Multiply two columns by a scalar

Tags: excel, excel-2008

I'd like to multiply the value of a given cell by a scalar and output the result to an adjacent cell. For example, if I had:

```
     B    C
1    25   ?
2    20   ?
3    21   ?
4    23   ?
```

I want the `?` values in each C column to be `20 * (B in same row)`. i.e. (`C1 = B1*20, C2=B2*20, C3=B3*20, ...`). I know I could do this individually for each row, but I'm hoping to do it for the entire column at once.

I'm using Excel 2008 for Mac if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a "Fill Down" menu item somewhere; otherwise you can copy `C1`, highlight the appropriate cells in `C` and paste.  Excel handles changing the row numbers for you.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I thought I had tried that already but I guess not :)